# How to generate Castor mapping.xml file from given multiple XSDs?

Tags: xsd, mapping, castor

How to generate Castor mapping.xml file from given multiple XSDs?

Answer (score 0):

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

//import org.exolab.castor.builder.SourceGenerator;
import org.exolab.castor.mapping.MappingException;
import org.exolab.castor.tools.MappingTool;

public class CastorMappingToolUtil {

```
public static void generate() throws MappingException, FileNotFoundException {
    MappingTool tool = new MappingTool();
    tool.setInternalContext(new org.castor.xml.BackwardCompatibilityContext());
    tool.addClass(ClassType.class);
    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/xmlFile/gen_mapping.xml" ); 

    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(file);
    tool.write(writer);
    //SourceGenerator.main(options);
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        CastorMappingToolUtil.generate();
    } catch (MappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does **Castor-0.9.5.4** version support this? I could not find `BackwardCompatibilityContext` class in there.

Comment: Hi tamerrab, how do did you input your xsd here to generate mapping.xml file? The code above just generates a two liner stub. here is my similar post on the topic but haven't found any solutions yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426218/generate-castor-xml-from-xsd?noredirect=1#comment43304990_27426218