# Generate castor xml from xsd

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, castor

I am currently using the Jaxb for Marshalling/Unmarshalling. However I need to use castor due to "demands" and use castor xml instead of castor java classes. I found castor's SourceGeneratorMain which generates xsd to java classes, but I cannot find anything that generates castor xml from xsd. I would just type it out but the xsd im working is huge with more than 2500 lines and over a hundered parameter various arrays in there. Im sure Im going to screw up something, if I type it out.

Has any one used any sort of tool to do this? or what is the most efficient way to get a castor xml from a xsd.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "castor xml", exactly?

Comment: It's something like this: http://castor.codehaus.org/1.2/xml-mapping.html. search for mapping.xml. It has tags like field, bind-xml etc.. used by castor for mapping.

Comment: Ok, so you're looking for a tool to generate Castor XML mapping out of the XML Schema?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737063/how-to-generate-castor-mapping-xml-file-from-given-multiple-xsds

Comment: Yea I saw that. But it dosen't have a input for a xsd file. That code just generates a 2 liner stub. Was going to ask on the comments but, I dont have enough rep.